# cannot get into corrupted user profile to retrieve live mail address book

Tags: email, data-recovery

Wife's computer will not allow her to logon.  Says profile corrupted and we set up new user profile.  Only thing is that she cannot get into her address book from old profile to copy over to new live mail.  Can this be done since old profile will not allow logon?

Comment: If Windows Vista/7/8: If you have access to an administrative account then, yes, you can gain ownership of the profile which will give you access to the files and folders within. Logon as an admin account -> go to `c:\Users\<broken_user>` - you should be prompted that you need to take ownership before you can gain access -> click to agree to this -> you should then have unrestricted access to the files/folders

Answer (score 0):

If the corrupted computer can still load, but not allow one to logon, then you may be able to use a rescue disk/usb drive to boot and then access the files directly.

On a Window system, you have a password and profile, but this actually does not protect the files natively at the disk level. If you are using full disk encryption, then a recovery disc may not work, unless it is a special one that words with the encryption software.

Depending in your situation, there are a few ways to address this issue, but here is [a tutorial](https://www.winhelp.us/recover-files-using-puppy-linux.html) which seems to apply generally and may help you with further research,